# how to bind nested inputs using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a from where I want to bind all the nested input fields of each radio button to it's option so I can show the results when it's clicked.  For example if option1 is selected the only results shown would be nested inputs of option1. How can I do it using knockout.js and jQuery?

```html
<div id="results" class="jumbotron">
  <!-- ko if : option1 -->
  <ul data-bind="text: input1"></ul>
  ...
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko if : option2 -->
  ...
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko if : option2 -->
  ...
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

What is the right syntax to write an if statement block in knockout.js that checks radio buttons value?

```js
var viewModel = {
  optionRadio: ko.observable("option1"),
  input1: ko.observable(),
  input2: ko.observable(),
  input3: ko.observable(false),
  input4: ko.observable(false),
  optionValues: ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"],
  selectedOptionValue: ko.observable("Gamma")
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

var jsonData = ko.toJSON(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results" class="jumbotron">
<!-- ko if : option1 -->
<ul data-bind="text: input1"></ul>
<ul data-bind="text: input2"></ul>
<ul>
  <!-- ko if : input3 -->
  <li data-bind="text : input3"></li>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko if : input4 -->
  <li data-bind="text : input4"></li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
<ul data-bind="text: selectedOptionValue"></ul>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if : option2 -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if : option2 -->
<!-- /ko -->
</div>

<hr>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionRadio" value="option1" data-bind="checked: optionRadio" />Option 1
      </label>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Input 1</label>
          <input data-bind="textInput: input1" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Input 2</label>
          <input data-bind="textInput: input2" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input data-bind="checked: input3" type="checkbox" />option 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input data-bind="checked: input4" type="checkbox" />option 2</label>
        </div>
        <select data-bind="options: optionValues, value: selectedOptionValue"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionRadio" value="option2" data-bind="checked: optionRadio" />Option 2
      </label>
      <ul>Some content here</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionRadio" value="option3" data-bind="checked: optionRadio" />Option 3
      </label>
      <ul>Some other content here</ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: something like this you looking for http://jsfiddle.net/74dh736s/28/ . cheers

Comment: @supercool this is great. Now how can I replace this: 

<!-- ko if : try1 -->
    <ul data-bind="text: input1"></ul>
    ...
<!-- /ko -->
   
to show the result of user inputs on the same page?

Comment: yes you should be doing like this . sample here http://jsfiddle.net/74dh736s/29/ . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments you should be doing like this .

**ViewModel:**

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.optionRadio = ko.observable();
    self.input1 = ko.observable();
    self.input2 = ko.observable();
    self.try1 = ko.observable();
    self.try2 = ko.observable();
    self.try3 = ko.observable();
    self.input3 = ko.observable(false);
    self.input4 = ko.observable(false);
    self.optionRadio.subscribe(function (s) {
        if (s == 'option1') {
            self.try1(true);
            self.try2(false);
            self.try3(false);
        } else if (s == 'option2') {
              self.try1(false);
            self.try2(true);
            self.try3(false);
        } else {
            self.try1(false);
            self.try2(false);
            self.try3(true);
        }
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

**View :**

```
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optionRadio" value="option2" data-bind="checked: optionRadio" />Option 2</label>
            <ul data-bind="visible:try2">Some content here</ul>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optionRadio" value="option3" data-bind="checked: optionRadio" />Option 3</label>
            <ul data-bind="visible:try3">Some other content here</ul>
        </div>
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/74dh736s/31/)**

Comment: do you have any idea why the input1 and input2 are not bind to the View?

Comment: Because of textInput i guess try using value binding with events i.e valueUpdate:'keyup' etc (updated fiddle) cheers